# Ubuntu Server SSH does not autostart

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.04, service, daemon

I use a VPS with Ubuntu 10.04. After I performed "apt-get upgrade", the ssh daemon stopped working and does not automatically start when I restart my server. I have only access to files (edit, create delete etc.) and no shell access. Could you please help me out with setting up SSH Daemon autostart? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you can edit files, you can access the log files. Are there any informations in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: For what should I look for inside the log file?

Comment: Anything that looks related to the failed start of the SSH daemon.

Comment: ssh or sshd are referred nowhere inside the file.

Comment: you should look inside /var/log/auth.log ...should give TIMESTAMP SERVERNAME sshd[8355]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
TIMESTAMP SERVERNAME sshd[8355]: Server listening on :: port 22 on successful startup of sshd daemon

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid without shell access, there is little we could do to diagnose the problem. Does your VPS comes with control panel of any sort ? if they do provide that , their should be direct console access from there otherwise you will have to contact a support person from VPS company that has direct access to the server.

Comment: I use the Virtuozzo Control panel, but it does not give me shell access.

Comment: I don't have any experience with virtuozzo control panel. Best option would be to contact the person who has a physical access to the machine which hosts the VPS in your case.